# Cannot login to phpmyadmin with root, there is two root users and can login to mysql without password

Tags: apache2, login, mysql, phpmyadmin

Following [this](https://devanswers.co/installing-phpmyadmin-apache-ubuntu-18-04/) tutorial, everything works fine, till the moment when I tried to login to my phpmyadmin with root and password:

**Problem 1** (cannot login to phpmyadmin):

```
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

**Problem 2** (no password requires when login during console with:

```
sudo mysql
```

**Problem 3** (there is two users with 'root' name):

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

returns me

```
User             | Host
root             | %
debian-sys-maint | localhost
mysql.infoschema | localhost
mysql.session    | localhost
mysql.sys        | localhost
root             | localhost
```

**I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS**

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

As said in the tutorial, you have to create a user named phpmyadmin to access the website.

**Solution 2**

It doesn't ask you for your password since sudo means you are executing `mysql` as root, thus removing the need for a password.

**Solution 3**

If there is no data in the database, you can remove the % one I believe, since the important one is `'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: Ok I did these two commands `CREATE USER 'pmauser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password_here';` and `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pmauser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` now I can login with `pmauser` and password to phpmyadmin, but why I cannot use root user ?

Comment: I believe phpmyadmin disables root user by default for security reasons. Not sure...

Answer (score 1):

I found info about **Problem 1**:

> In MySQL 5.7 (released Oct 2015), the root MySQL user is set to
>   authenticate using the auth_socket plugin rather than with a password.
>   This will prevent programs like phpMyAdmin from logging in with the
>   root account.
>
> You can either create a new MySQL superuser just for phpMyAdmin or you
>   can try changing the authentication method for root. Personally I
>   would recommend creating a new superuser as it’s not a good idea to
>   allow the root account to be accessed via phpMyAdmin.

Answer above answers **Problem 2** and **Problem 3**